# How to run a vb program from first from

Tags: vb.net, forms

When I run my Visual Basic program it opens the fourth form, not the first. How can I Make it run from the first form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the project's 'Startup form'.

See this article for explicit details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984318%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you Sam, got it working!!

Comment: No problem.  If you're sorted can you mark the answer as correct?  Thanks!